# Unexpected result on Gmail using AMP

Tags: email, gmail, amp-html, amp-email

I just learnt about this new extension of HTML and wanted to learn something about it.

I have sent to my Gmail account a test from their [Playground](https://playground.amp.dev/) to my Gmail account and it worked fine.

Now, I do the same using my valid mail system with **SPF**, **DKIM** and **DMARC** (following the requirements from their documentation) and when it arrives, it looks broken. The amp-html is not even close to the one I've built using the playground.

**What I am missing?**

- I have whitelisted the mail
- I allow to receive dynamic mail from a sender (my ESP)

Here is the template I used for the test

```
<!--
  ## Introduction

  The [amp-carousel](/content/amp-dev/documentation/components/reference/amp-carousel-v0.2.md) component allows displaying multiple similar pieces of content along a horizontal axis.
--><!-- -->
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>amp-carousel</title>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <!-- ## Setup -->
  <!-- Import the carousel component in the header. -->
  <script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.1.js"></script>
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-carousel/index.html">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  <style amp-custom>
    .blue-box, .red-box, .green-box {
      width: 100%;
      height: 280px;
    }
    .blue-box {
      background: blue;
    }
    .green-box {
      background: green;
    }
    .red-box {
      background: red;
    }
    #custom-button .amp-carousel-button-prev {
      left: 5%;
      background-image: url('https://amp.dev/static/samples/img/carousel-arrow-left.png');
    }
    #custom-button .amp-carousel-button-next {
      right: 5%;
      background-image: url('https://amp.dev/static/samples/img/carousel-arrow-right.png');
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- ## Basic Usage -->
  <!-- Use `type="carousel"` to display a list of images as a continuous strip. -->
  <amp-carousel height="300" layout="fixed-height" type="carousel">
    <amp-img src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/samples/img/image1.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="a sample image"></amp-img>
    <amp-img src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/samples/img/image2.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="another sample image"></amp-img>
    <amp-img src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/samples/img/image3.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="and another sample image"></amp-img>
  </amp-carousel>

  <!-- ## Slides -->
  <!-- Use `type="slides"` to display a list of images as slides. -->
  <amp-carousel width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" type="slides">
    <amp-img src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/samples/img/image1.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" alt="a sample image"></amp-img>
    <amp-img src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/samples/img/image2.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" alt="another sample image"></amp-img>
    <amp-img src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/samples/img/image3.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" alt="and another sample image"></amp-img>
  </amp-carousel>

  <!-- ## Autoplay -->
  <!-- The `autoplay` attribute (type=slides only) advances the slide to the next slide without user interaction, by default it will advance a slide in 5000 millisecond intervals (5 seconds) and can be overridden by the `delay` attribute.  -->
  <amp-carousel width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" type="slides" autoplay delay="2000">
    <amp-img src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/samples/img/image1.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" alt="a sample image"></amp-img>
    <amp-img src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/samples/img/image2.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" alt="another sample image"></amp-img>
    <amp-img src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/samples/img/image3.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" alt="and another sample image"></amp-img>
  </amp-carousel>

  <!-- ## Buttons -->
  <!-- By default, carousel buttons use inlined SVGs as background-images.
    You may override these with your own SVGs or images by using `.amp-carousel-button-prev` and `.amp-carousel-button-next` classes. -->
  <amp-carousel id="custom-button" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" type="slides" autoplay delay="2000">
    <amp-img src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/samples/img/image1.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" alt="a sample image"></amp-img>
    <amp-img src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/samples/img/image2.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" alt="another sample image"></amp-img>
    <amp-img src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/samples/img/image3.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" alt="and another sample image"></amp-img>
  </amp-carousel>

  <!-- ## Supported Contents  -->
  <!-- Each of these nodes may also have arbitrary HTML children.  -->
  <amp-carousel height="300" layout="fixed-height" type="slides">
    <div>
      <div class="blue-box">
        This is a blue box.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="red-box">
        This is a red box.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="green-box">
        This is a green box.
      </div>
    </div>
  </amp-carousel>
  <!-- A good use case for `amp-carousel` are image galleries, [here](/documentation/examples/multimedia-animations/image_galleries_with_amp-carousel/) are some examples. -->
</body></html>
```

I've read other solutions but those are using .NET, C#, Python and other solutions regarding custom made software to send these kind of mails, but what about big bulk emailing services such as XCampaign, SalesForce, Selligent, etc?

**Do they need an upgrade to allow AMP emailing?**

Comment: AMP uses a separate MIME type - your sending platform needs to support it. https://go.amp.dev/email-tools lists some of the platforms and ESPs that support this, but it's best to reach out to your ESP's support to ask if they support this and how to enable AMP if they do.

Comment: @fstanis Thanks, I will look into it!. Although, if you elaborate an answer for those who find this question I will totally accept it.